# Remove all but numerical values from a String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and want to know what's the most efficient way to extract Integer values from Strings like below:

```
const String1 = '122,730 views'
const String2 = '2,990 likes'
```

Output:

```
122730
2990
```

Is there a JS function to remove all but numerical values from a String? In this case, `parseInt()` would just return `122` and `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScripts `parseInt()` function does not know any thousands separator.
You can just simply replace them beforehand.

```js
const String1 = '122,730 views';
const Value1 = parseInt(String1.replace(/,/g, ""));

console.log(Value1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Regex](https://regex101.com/) like this:

```js
const regex = /[0-9+]/gm;
const str = `122,730 views`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}
```

P.S. I'm sorry I didn't comment, but It's impossible, because of my low reputation.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function retnum(str) {
  var num = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  return parseInt(num, 10);
}

console.log('122,730 views'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
console.log(retnum('122,730 views'));
```